# Is there a way to avoid keyboard latency in javascript/browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, keyboard, latency

If you play this piano you feel a huge latency while playing. I want to avoid the latency because it is very annoying. I Fruity Loops, installing ASIO Plugin remove the latency. Anything like that or is there some black magic to make it works?

https://codepen.io/Schizomaru/pen/OjLyNX

```
$(function(){

    var $keyboard = $('.keyboard')
      , $buttons = $keyboard.find('button')
      , charMap = {}
      , keyList = []
      , char
      , audioCtx = new AudioContext()
      , oscMap = {};

    for(var i=0; i < $buttons.length; i++){
        char = $buttons[i].innerHTML;
        keyList.push(charMap[char] = {
            $button: $($buttons[i]),
            index:i,
            char:char,
            playing:false
        });
    }

    function getFreq(i){
        return 220 * Math.pow(2, (i+3)/12);
    }

    function playNote(obj, playing){
        if(obj && obj.playing != playing){
            obj.playing = playing;
            if(playing){
                if(!obj.osc){
                    obj.osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
                    obj.osc.type = 'square';
                    obj.osc.frequency.value = getFreq(obj.index);
                    obj.osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

                }
                obj.osc.start();
            } else {
                if(obj.osc){
                    obj.osc.stop();
                    obj.osc = null;
                }
            }
         obj.$button[playing ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('playing');
        }

    }

    $(window).on('keydown keyup', function(e){
        var c = e.originalEvent.key || '';
        playNote(charMap[c.toUpperCase()], e.type == 'keydown');
    });

    $keyboard.on('mousedown mouseup', 'button', function(e){
        var c = this.innerHTML;
        playNote(charMap[c.toUpperCase()], e.type == 'mousedown');
    })

})
```

Comment: **Headphone Users Beware**: Before testing the codepen, turn your volume way down.

Comment: I experienced (minor pain but) no latency using mouse clicks on Chrome on desktop Win7. Is the latency you're experiencing on a specific configuration of browser > OS; is it when using a mouse, keyboard or both?

Comment: Is it a touch screen? Use this: http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: I mean, keyboard latency, and can be used on touch screen. Not tested on touch screen yet. And yes, I need to implement a volume control, this can give a heart attack on a headphoe user =)

Comment: I did not experience latency while testing. Do you have this problem on click event as well? Also, you could optimize playNote by using left shift, like 2 << ((i+3)/12) instead of the slower Math.pow(2, (i+3)/12).